# ssh key exchange failed couldnt read packet

Tags: ssh

We had ssh file transfer connection between Unix and Windows box. Connection got broken and below is the error in detail

telnet to the Windows Server is working
while trying sftp we are getting below error

```
Received disconnect from Server name(Windows):Key exchange failed
Couldn't read packet:Connection reset by peer
```

It seems to be something with Permission to the keys on the Destination Windows Server where SSH TECTIA installed.

Please help us with your suggestions o fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have more safe authentification activated on the server while the client is an older one?

You could try "scp username@server:path/file destinationpath" instead of "sftp". Does this work? Does ssh work?
You could also try to use "winscp" on a windows machine.

One of them might give you a more descriptive error message.

Comment: I tired scp and nothing is showing up. Could you please correct me the syntax if it is wrong                                                                         
scp userid@server filename F/destinationfolder/                                                                                                                                                                                 
One more thing is the Destination windows box is a old Server and I dont know whether we can install WINSCP on that machine.

Comment: What means "nothing shows up"? No error message and does the command just hang? Your syntax is wrong. <br> scp username@server:filename destinationfolder

Comment: ... like this (copy files to current directory): scp -r root@192.168.0.49:/usr/local/bin/* .

Comment: I am gettig the same error Received disconnect from Server name(Windows):Key exchange failed

Comment: I don't know the tectia server, but... Can you change the key exchange methods (could be called KexAlgorithms or similar) on your server? I had a similar problem one with two linux machines. I had to activate sha1 (diffie-hellman-group1-sha1). Sha1 is not considered to be save anymore, therefore it is not enabled by default on most actual servers. My older linux client however could not speak the newer protocols.